# End of scrollbar listbox was split and one of my listheaders is not appearing

Tags: java, zk

I am trying to create a `listbox` inside a `groupbox` component which has eight columns. However the last column is gone and I don't know why, even though my listbox has a horizontal scrollbar. I've tried to add:

```
`<library-property>    
  <name>org.zkoss.zul.nativebar</name>    
  <value>true</value>
</library-property>`
```

In my **zk.xml** and many things
but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
<groupbox
    visible="@bind(vm.gbxGridPo)"  width="100%">
    <caption label="${labels.common.label.hasil_pencarian}" style="color:blue" />
    <vlayout >
        <checkbox  name="chkBPKB" label="Print SPP/SIP BPKB" checked="@bind(vm.chkBPKB)" />
        <listbox model="@load(vm.poDTOs)" mold="paging" pageSize="10"
                 emptyMessage="Tidak ada data" checkmark="true"
                 width="97%" style="overflow:hidden"
                 selectedItem="@bind(vm.aksiSelectedPO)"
                 onClick="@command('onCheckRadio')">
            <listhead  >
                 <listheader label="${labels.common.label.pilih}" align="center" width="50px" />
                 <listheader label="${labels.common.label.sentra}" align="center" sort="auto(sentraID)"  width="150px" />
                 <listheader label="${labels.common.label.unit}" align="center" sort="auto(unitID)" width="150px" />
                 <listheader label="${labels.common.label.jenis_pihak_ketiga}" align="center" sort="auto(thirdPartyTypeID)" width="150px" />
                 <listheader label="${labels.common.label.nama_pihak_ketiga}" align="center" sort="auto(thirdPartyName)" width="150px"  />
                 <listheader label="${labels.common.label.no_po}" align="center" sort="auto(poNumber)"  width="120px"/>
                 <listheader label="${labels.common.label.nama_lengkap}" align="center" sort="auto(customerName)" width="180px" />
                 <listheader label="${labels.common.label.no_aplikasi}" align="center" sort="auto(orderID)" width="140px"/>
             </listhead>
             <template name="model"  status="s" var="item">
                 <listitem>  
                     <listcell />
                     <listcell label="@load(item.sentraID)" />
                     <listcell label="@load(item.unitID)" />
                     <listcell label="@load(item.thirdPartyTypeID)" />
                     <listcell label="@load(item.thirdPartyName)" /> 
                     <listcell label="@load(item.poNumber)" /> 
                     <listcell label="@load(item.customerName)" /> 
                     <listcell label="@load(item.orderID)" /> 
                 </listitem>                               
            </template>  
        </listbox>
    </vlayout>
</groupbox>
```

[image: This is my screen shoot]

Comment: Please reduce your zul to the bare minimum that's necessary to reproduce the behavior. With all those bindings for example, it is not possible to immediately use your zul without cleaning those and replacing them with fixed text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ideas about what is going wrong:

First, setting the `vlayout`'s width to 100% or hflex to 1 could help. Right now, the `vlayout` will be as wide as necessary to fit its children. The 97% on the `listbox` don't help, since the parent (`vlayout`) does not have a width restriction.

Second, is the 100% on `groupbox` correct? What container is that one in? If the `groupbox`'s container spans the whole page, 100% will make the groupbox also span the whole page; and since there is another box on the left, the `groupbox` is extends beyond the page.

**EDIT**

After playing with your zul a bit, I think it is the second case. Look at this zul:

```
<hlayout width="100%">
    <div width="100px" height="100px" style="background: green" />
    <groupbox width="100%">
        <caption label="Bla" />
        <vlayout >
            <checkbox  label="Check" />
            <listbox model="@load(vm.poDTOs)" width="97%" style="overflow:hidden">
                <listhead  >
                     <listheader label="1" width="50px" />
                     <listheader label="2" width="150px" />
                     <listheader label="2" width="150px" />
                     <listheader label="2" width="150px" />
                     <listheader label="2" width="150px" />
                     <listheader label="2" width="150px" />
                     <listheader label="2" width="150px" />
                     <listheader label="2" width="150px" />
                     <listheader label="2" width="150px" />
                 </listhead>
            </listbox>
        </vlayout>
    </groupbox>
</hlayout>
```

This produces behavior looking similar to yours. But changing the `groupbox` from `width="100%"` to `hflex="1"` fixes it, as it will only take the remaining space left behind the `div`.

Comment: awesome thank you @Malte Hartwig, finally i got it i am folowing your example and changing a bit your code, i set `<hlayout width="90%" visible="@bind(vm.gbxGridPo)">` and  `<vlayout hflex="1" width="80%">`  then set the `listbox width="90%"` working perfectly.